# How to bind xsd file correctly in C# WPF for example to show some elements of the schema?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xsd

Let's say I have a **WPF** project in VisualStudio and an **xsd** file which I need to **bind** to and **show** some of the elements in a **combobox**. Below is an **example** of **xsd** which I have and my **xaml**. It looks like it should be a straight forward thing but it just does not work. Could you please help me?

Edit 1: I know that **xsd is not the source** of data but it is **an xml document by itself**. And for example there might be need to give user a look over what options are available.

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema id="TypedDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
            <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" 
                        FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" 
                        Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" 
                        SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" 
                        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
                <Connections />
                <Tables />
                <Sources />
            </DataSource>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="TypedDataSet">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" 
                       maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Orders">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="OrderID" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="OrderTypeID" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="OrderDate" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="OrderTypes">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="OrderTypeID" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="OrderTypeName" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="Rank" 
                                        type="xs:string" 
                                        minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Test" Source="C:\Test\Test.xsd"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test}, XPath=xs://element}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="@name"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You cannot bind to a schema.  The schema is only the structure and doesn't contain any data.  The data is in the xml file and you have to bind to the data.

Comment: xsd is an xml document itself, isn't it? Let's say I just want to get all elements' names.

Comment: An xsd (schema) has an xml structure but doesn't contain data.  the schema is used to validate the actual xml data file which has an extension xml (not xsd).

Comment: Is a list of elements' names in xsd not data? Or you mean it is not data from the WPF data binding view?

Comment: Element Names(Tag) are in schema and default values, but not data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching here and there I found the solution. Basically, all you need is to add **XmlNamespaceManager** and use **prefix** in XPath. As it looks now the actual problem was not about xsd but rather a namespace/prefix.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Test" Source="C:\Test\Test.xsd" XPath="xs:schema">
        <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
            <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                <XmlNamespaceMapping Uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Prefix="xs"/>
            </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
        </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test}, XPath=//xs:element}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="@name"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```